# How to add html code in "header.php" file?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to add my own `header.html` code to my theme, but I don't know how to add this code to `header.php` of theme directory? Actually, I'm not familiar with php at all and its not so easy to insert an html code into a php file. It becomes too complicated for a newbie to interpret the code of php and add the html accordingly.

Following is the `header.php` of my theme:

```
<?php
/**
 * The header for our theme.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all of the <head> section and everything up until <div id="content">
 *
 * @package Newsup
 */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?> >
<?php wp_body_open(); ?>
<div id="page" class="site">
<a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content">
<?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'newsup' ); ?></a>
    <div class="wrapper" id="custom-background-css">
        <header class="mg-headwidget">
            <!--==================== TOP BAR ====================-->

            <?php do_action('newsup_action_header_section');  ?>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <?php $background_image = get_theme_support( 'custom-header', 'default-image' );
            if ( has_header_image() ) {
              $background_image = get_header_image();
            } ?>
            <div class="mg-nav-widget-area-back" style='background-image: url("<?php echo esc_url( $background_image ); ?>" );'>
            <?php $remove_header_image_overlay = get_theme_mod('remove_header_image_overlay',false); ?>
            <div class="overlay">
              <div class="inner" <?php if($remove_header_image_overlay == false) { 
            $newsup_header_overlay_color = get_theme_mod('newsup_header_overlay_color','rgba(32,47,91,0.4)');?> style="background-color:<?php echo esc_attr($newsup_header_overlay_color);?>;" <?php } ?>> 
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="mg-nav-widget-area">
                        <div class="row align-items-center">
                            <?php $newsup_center_logo_title = get_theme_mod('newsup_center_logo_title',false);
                            if($newsup_center_logo_title == false) {
                             ?>
                            <div class="col-md-3 text-center-xs">
                                <?php } else { ?> 
                             <div class="col-md-12 text-center mx-auto">       
                                <?php } ?>
                                <div class="navbar-header">
                                <?php the_custom_logo(); 
                                if (display_header_text()) : ?>
                                <div class="site-branding-text">
                                <?php if (is_front_page() || is_home()) { ?>
                                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php echo esc_html(get_bloginfo( 'name' )); ?></a></h1>
                               <?php } else { ?>
                                <p class="site-title"> <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php echo esc_html(get_bloginfo( 'name' )); ?></a></p>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <p class="site-description"><?php echo esc_html(get_bloginfo( 'description' )); ?></p>
                                </div>
                              <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                           <?php do_action('newsup_action_banner_advertisement'); ?>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
          </div>
    <div class="mg-menu-full">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-wp">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <!-- Right nav -->
                    <div class="m-header align-items-center">
                        <?php $home_url = home_url(); ?>
                        <a class="mobilehomebtn" href="<?php echo esc_url($home_url); ?>"><span class="fas fa-home"></span></a>
                        <!-- navbar-toggle -->
                        <button class="navbar-toggler mx-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-wp" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e('Toggle navigation','newsup'); ?>">
                          <span class="burger">
                            <span class="burger-line"></span>
                            <span class="burger-line"></span>
                            <span class="burger-line"></span>
                          </span>
                        </button>
                        <!-- /navbar-toggle -->
                        <?php $header_search_enable = get_theme_mod('header_search_enable','true');
                        if($header_search_enable == true) {
                        ?>
                        <div class="dropdown show mg-search-box pr-2">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle msearch ml-auto" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                               <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                            </a> 
                            <div class="dropdown-menu searchinner" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      <?php } 
                      $header_subsc_enable = get_theme_mod('header_subsc_enable','true');
                      $subsc_target = get_theme_mod('newsup_subsc_link_target','true');
                      $newsup_subsc_link = get_theme_mod('newsup_subsc_link','#');
                      if($header_subsc_enable == true) {
                      ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url($newsup_subsc_link); ?>" <?php if($subsc_target) { ?> target="_blank" <?php } ?>  class="btn-bell btn-theme mx-2"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i></a>
                    <?php } ?>
                        
                    </div>
                    <!-- /Right nav -->
         
          
                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-wp">
                    <div class="d-md-block">
                  <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                                        'theme_location' => 'primary',
                                        'container'  => 'nav-collapse collapse',
                                        'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav mr-auto',
                                        'fallback_cb' => 'newsup_fallback_page_menu',
                                        'walker' => new newsup_nav_walker()
                                    ) ); 
                                ?>
                        </div>      
                    </div>

                    <!-- Right nav -->
                    <div class="desk-header d-lg-flex pl-3 ml-auto my-2 my-lg-0 position-relative align-items-center">
                        <!-- /navbar-toggle -->
                        <?php $header_search_enable = get_theme_mod('header_search_enable','true');
                        if($header_search_enable == true) {
                        ?>
                        <div class="dropdown show mg-search-box pr-2">
                            

                            <a class="dropdown-toggle msearch ml-auto" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                               <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                            </a>

                            <div class="dropdown-menu searchinner" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      <?php } 
                      $header_subsc_enable = get_theme_mod('header_subsc_enable','true');
                      $subsc_target = get_theme_mod('newsup_subsc_link_target','true');
                      $newsup_subsc_link = get_theme_mod('newsup_subsc_link','#');
                      if($header_subsc_enable == true) {
                      ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url($newsup_subsc_link); ?>" <?php if($subsc_target) { ?> target="_blank" <?php } ?>  class="btn-bell btn-theme mx-2"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i></a>
                    <?php }  ?>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /Right nav -->
          </div>
      </nav> <!-- /Navigation -->
    </div>
</header>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php  if (is_front_page() || is_home()) { ?>
<?php $show_popular_tags_title = newsup_get_option('show_popular_tags_title');
 $select_popular_tags_mode = newsup_get_option('select_popular_tags_mode');
 $number_of_popular_tags = newsup_get_option('number_of_popular_tags');
 newsup_list_popular_taxonomies($select_popular_tags_mode, $show_popular_tags_title, $number_of_popular_tags); ?>
 <?php } ?>
 <?php do_action('newsup_action_banner_exclusive_posts'); 
 do_action('newsup_action_front_page_main_section_1'); ?>
```

And this is my `header.html` code:

```
<div class="fixed w-full bg-white top-0 z-20" >
  <header class="w-full h-auto border-b-2 text-gray-300 text-mont font-medium text-sm text-gray" style="color: #bdbdbd;">
    <div class="flex justify-between container mx-auto py-2" >
      <div >
        <label class="text-sm text-mont text-gray font-semibold focus:outline-none cursor-pointer" style="color: #bdbdbd;">
          <select class="w-11" >
            <option value="en" >En</option>
            <option value="es" >Spanish</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="flex flex-row" >
        <div class="mr-3" ><a href="" style="cursor: pointer;">Latest News</a></div>
        <div ><a href="/zakat" style="cursor: pointer;">Zakat Calculator</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex flex-row" >
        <button class="flex gap-3 items-center text-blue text-sm text-mont font-bold" style="color: #00ade9;">
          <img class="" src="https://aidhumanity.org.uk/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/icon_phone-volume.svg" alt="Phone" >0330 057 9957
        </button>
        <div class="h-4 w-px border-l border-gray-300 mx-4" ></div>
        <div ><a href="/contact" style="cursor: pointer;">Contact Us</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div >
    <header class="w-full h-auto top-0 left-0 lg:px-0 px-5 py-1 relative container mx-auto" >
      <nav class="w-full h-auto" >
        <div class="w-full h-auto py-4 flex justify-between items-center" >
          <div class="w-96 h-auto" >
            <a href="/" style="cursor: pointer;"><img class="w-full" src="https://aidhumanity.org.uk/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/logo_aid-humanity.svg" alt="logo" ></a>
          </div>
          <div class="h-6 w-px border-l-2 border-gray-200 mx-8" ></div>
          <div class="text-lg text-mont text-black-50 font-semibold w-2/3 h-auto flex gap-4 justify-around items-center" style="color: #1d1d1d;">
            <a href="/story" class="whitespace-nowrap font-bold" style="cursor: pointer;">Our Story</a>
            <a href="/appeals" class="font-bold" style="cursor: pointer;">Appeals</a>
            <a class="font-bold" style="cursor: pointer;">Emergency</a>
            <a href="/zakat" class="font-bold" style="cursor: pointer;">Zakat</a>
            <a href="/contact" class="font-bold whitespace-nowrap" style="cursor: pointer;">Get Involved</a>
          </div>
          <div class="flex gap-4 items-center justify-end w-2/3" >
            <a class="invisible text-sm text-mont text-gray font-semibold" href="/zakat" style="cursor: pointer;color: #bdbdbd;">Zakat Calculator</a>
            <div class="invisible h-6 w-px border-l-2 border-gray-200 ml-5" ></div>
            <label class="invisible text-sm text-mont text-gray font-semibold focus:outline-none cursor-pointer" style="color: #bdbdbd;">En
              <select >
                <option value="en" >English</option>
                <option value="es" >Spanish</option>
              </select>
              <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down" ></i>
            </label>
            <a class="text-sm text-mont text-black-50 hover:text-sblue font-semibold flex justify-center items-center gap-2" style="cursor: pointer;color: #1d1d1d;">
              <img alt="header-icon" src="https://aidhumanity.org.uk/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/icon_user_circle.svg" class="w-6 h-6 rounded-full" >
              <span class="whitespace-nowrap" >My Account</span>
            </a>
            <a class="relative" href="" style="cursor: pointer;">
              <img src="https://aidhumanity.org.uk/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/icon_package-box.svg" alt="package-box" >
              <p class="px-1.5 py-px text-vs bg-blue rounded-full absolute bottom-0 -right-1 text-white" style="background-color: #00ade9;font-size: 8px;">1</p>
            </a>
            
            <a href="/appeals" class="ml-4 text-dblue hover:text-white text-center font-semibold text-sm border-sblue border-2 hover:bg-sblue rounded-lg px-4 py-2 whitespace-nowrap" style="cursor: pointer;border-color: #00ade9;color: #006ba3;">DONATE NOW</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can manually wedge html code into the header file, in modern wordpress, the accepted way to add code to your header or footer is to add it through functions.php as actions.  The code gets incorporated as part of the workflow behind the scenes.

Just find your functions.php file in your theme root folder. If if doesn't exist, create it.

Here is an example:

```
/* Describe what the code snippet does so you can remember later on */
add_action('wp_head', 'your_function_name');
function your_function_name(){
?>
PASTE HEADER CODE HERE
<?php
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to include the HTML file in your php file.  Below example is assuming they are in the same directory, you would add the following to your header.php file where you want header.html inserted

```
<?php include 'header.html'; ?>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: The issue is that the directory is saved at the server and I don't have access to that. I need to do something in Theme File Editor. Or can use a plugin.

Comment: Are you saying that header.html is not stored within the theme?  If you modify the theme locally and put header.html in the same directory as header.php, you can edit header.php and upload the whole theme without access to the server filesystem.